# Textview not able to move up when begin editing

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ios6

I am having problem moving up my `UITextview` at the bottom.

The `UITextField` is working properly but the `UITextView` is not working.

Here is my code when press the TextView it pop up the toolbar. Please help

```
- (IBAction)HideKeyboard:(id)sender {
    [self.myTextField resignFirstResponder];
    [self.myTextView resignFirstResponder];
    [self.myScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: self.myTextView.delegate = YES ? kindly check this.. you might have missed it.

Comment: No I already set textview delegate.Do you know why ?

Comment: is it supposed to be `[self.myTextView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES];` instead?

Comment: Please provide more code that you have tried. So that one can be able to understand your issue and help you.

Comment: Do you want to hide the keyboard or to show the keyboard ? Or do you want to move the textview ?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you need to move the UITextView above the keyboard then try the following approach

Add [TPKeyboardAvoiding Framework](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding) to your project which will take care of moving the `UITextField's` and `UITextView's` above the keyboard.

Comment: @jason-lau If you find **any** of the answers useful please **upvote it** and if answer is correct then please **accept it** this will help to remove the question from the list of **unanswered list of question**

Answer (score 0):

Your TextView must be under the ScrollView.

Try this.

**In ViewdidLoad method** set notification for keyboard

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];

-(void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)notif
{

scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, scrollOriginalFrame.size.height+350);
    NSTimeInterval duration = 0.6;

if(txt_preRemindText.isFirstResponsder)
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:
         ^{
             [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,260) animated:YES];

         }];

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code .

//This code is add in below the import file .

```
static const CGFloat PORTRAIT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT = 216;
static const CGFloat LANDSCAPE_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT = 162;
static const CGFloat KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION = 0.3;
static const CGFloat MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION = 0.2;
static const CGFloat MAXIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION = 0.8;
```

//And after Add this function.

```
-(void) textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
```

{

```
CGRect textFieldRect = [self.view.window convertRect:textView.bounds fromView:textView];
CGRect viewRect = [self.view.window convertRect:self.view.bounds fromView:self.view];

CGFloat midline = textFieldRect.origin.y + 0.5 * textFieldRect.size.height;
CGFloat numerator = midline - viewRect.origin.y - MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION * viewRect.size.height;
CGFloat denominator = (MAXIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION - MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION) * viewRect.size.height;
CGFloat heightFraction = numerator / denominator;

if(heightFraction < 0.0)
{
    heightFraction = 0.0;
}
else if(heightFraction > 1.0)
{
    heightFraction = 1.0;
}

UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];

if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown){

    animatedDistance = floor(PORTRAIT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT * heightFraction);

}
else
{
    animatedDistance = floor(LANDSCAPE_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT * heightFraction);
}

CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
viewFrame.origin.y -= animatedDistance;

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION];

[self.view setFrame:viewFrame];

[UIView commitAnimations];
  }
```

//And add this method for textview

```
- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{

CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
viewFrame.origin.y += animatedDistance;
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION];

[self.view setFrame:viewFrame];
[UIView commitAnimations];
}


- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {
if ([text isEqualToString:@"\n"])
{
    [txt_description resignFirstResponder];
    return NO;
}
return YES;
```

}

Your View up if you editing in textview.